# Fixed full screen menu option - when clicked on the link the menu toggle should close

Tags: html, css

I have developed a code that works when the menu toggle is selected and closed when selected again. But, when the menu is open, and clicked on a link, the menu toggle (full fixed menu) doesn't go away. I want the full page fixed menu to disappear when the menu link is clicked.

HTML:

```
<!--NAVIGATION-->
    <div class="navigation">
      <input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="navi-toggle" />

      <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation__button">
        <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
      </label>

      <div class="navigation__background">&nbsp;</div>

      <nav class="navigation__nav">
        <ul class="navigation__list">
          <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#about_us" class="navigation__link"
              >About Bansuri Dabeli</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#menu" class="navigation__link">Our Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link">Testimonial</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#contact_us" class="navigation__link">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation__checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.navigation__button {
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation__background {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 2rem;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#2b2d6b, #2b2dbd);
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1),
    -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
}

.navigation__nav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1500;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.6, 0.32, 1.6);
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.6, 0.32, 1.6);
}

.navigation__list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation__item {
  margin: 2.5rem;
}

.navigation__link:link,
.navigation__link:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    120deg,
    transparent 0%,
    transparent 50%,
    #fff 50%
  );
  background-size: 220%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.navigation__link:link,
.navigation__link:visited,
.navigation__link:target {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.navigation__link:hover,
.navigation__link:active {
  background-position: 100%;
  color: #55c57a;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1rem);
  transform: translateX(1rem);
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__background {
  -webkit-transform: scale(80);
  transform: scale(80);
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation__icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.navigation__icon,
.navigation__icon::before,
.navigation__icon::after {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3.5px;
   background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation__icon::before,
.navigation__icon::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navigation__icon::before {
  top: -0.8rem;
}

.navigation__icon::after {
  top: 0.8rem;
}

.navigation__button:hover .navigation__icon::before {
  top: -1rem;
}

.navigation__button:hover .navigation__icon::after {
  top: 1rem;
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button .navigation__icon {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button .navigation__icon::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button .navigation__icon::after {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is impossible to do without JavaScript. You can add a simple script like:

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector('.navigation__checkbox');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__link');
const closeMenu = () => checkbox.checked = false;

links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', closeMenu));
```